# 1970s or '80s animated movie about a boy who visits an island or city populated by androids

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

I'm trying to identify an animated movie I saw in the theater around 1980. It was a children's matinee, so it may be older. In the movie, a boy visits an island or city where the inhabitants are all androids or robots. The island may have been operated or built by his relative... an uncle? Things go wrong, and he has to escape, chased by everyone.

The twist at the end was that as the boy was floating away on a boat, he started repeating himself like a broken record, thus revealing himself to be an android/robot also.

The only line I can remember from the movie was during the chase, when the villain shouted he was going to turn them into shish kebabs. Googling that phrase hasn't turned up any hits that I recognize.

Comment: In what country did you see it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Rankin-Bass stop-motion film [*Mad Monster Party*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061931/) from 1967?

> **On the Isle of Evil**, the head of the "World Organization of Monsters" reveals his imminent retirement and that he has refined a formula for total destruction, only to be upset when **the monsters try to steal the formula and kill his nephew.**

It ends with the nephew repeating the same words over and over, revealing himself to be his uncle's creation as well. Followed by the 1972 sort-of sequel [*Mad Mad Monsters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Mad_Mad_Monsters), this time in traditional animation. The trailer:

Comment: Monsters, not robots. That's it! It's funny what sticks in old memories.

Comment: Same answer, but different question. The only thing in common is uncle/nephew, and even that wasn't certain in my question.